# Docker Entry Point with Script Arguments

Tags: docker, wildfly

In `Dockerfile` we can define entry point as below :-

```
From Wildfly 
ENTRYPOINT["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

But i want to pass entry point while we start the container with some argument as below :-

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -Ddb_driver=mysql -b 0.0.0.0 -Duser=root  Wildfly
```

but its not working because docker try to evaluate script argument (-D and -b) as docker command parameter. I gave entrypoint in quote as well but its not working.

How can i pass script argument in docker entrypoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--entrypoint` only allows to specify a single string which is interpreted as name/path of the binary to start. This is different from what you can specify in the Dockerfile, as it allows to specify json arrays.

Also, `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfiles actually serves a different purpose then what you are using it for. `ENTRYPOINT` should only specify the entry binary to call, while `CMD` specifies the arguments to that binary. If there is no `ENTRYPOINT` specified, `CMD` becomes the entrypoint while also containing the arguments.

This should work for you:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh"]
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

When `docker run` is called without arguments now, it will use the value of `CMD` as arguments to the entrypoint. When it is called with arguments, the specified arguments are appended to the entrypoint instead of what was defined in `CMD`. For example:

```
docker run -it Wildfly -Ddb_driver=mysql -b 0.0.0.0 -Duser=root
```

Will run:

```
/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -Ddb_driver=mysql -b 0.0.0.0 -Duser=root
```